# SQL Server express edition in windows application - error message -26 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I am very new to programming. I created a windows application. Used SQL Server database as the DB for it (My application is really a small one having just 2 screens and 2 tables). I have copied the db file in the folder with executable, and connection string is pointed to it. In the computer I created this application, everything works fine(VS 2005, C#, Windows XP). it works fine in different discs of same machine. Now, when I copy it into another computer (Windows 7 Home premium) and open the exe file, I get the error message Why?

Is it that I am using the wrong database? I wanted a mbile DB which can be deployed with the application, without installing it on the machine. Should I move to Access DB or SQL Server Compact edition?

Answer (score 0):

Check the authentication for the user. on the other machine you may have different user credentials. Try to show your connectionstring that may give idea what is going on

Comment: I was using Integrated windos security and user name is different in both machines. Also in the new machine I dont have VS2005 or SQL Server Express edition installed. connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBNewJoinee.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: in your connection string u have . which means local server and you don't have sql server installed

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the SQL Server Compact edition database file (sdf) or a standard SQL Database file (mdf). I have had a number of problems using .sdf files with Visual Studio Express.

Comment: I am using an mdf file. connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBNewJoinee.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Answer (score 0):

Does new machine has MS SQL Installed?

Comment: No. My guess was, err... it doesnt need any, as I thought SQL Server MDB file is a portable DB.